# No matching provision profile found in submitting iOS app to iTune-connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

I am trying to submit my iOS app archive to iTune to distribute as TestFlight.

The is error as 
"No matching provisional profile found" as shown in the image.
[image]

When I checked in Xcode > General, I found the Provision Profile as XCode Managed Profile as shown in the image.

I go the Developer Portal and checked Provision Profiles. There is no profile named as `iOS Team Provisional Profile`. Is that the issue? Or if that is not the issue, why I have that error in submitting archive to iTune? Or Where can I find the Team Provisional Profile?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution for that is

(1)uncheck the automatic manage signing

(2)create a new distribution provision profile for the app

(3)download and use that for the provision profile.

Then it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to iTunes and create a profile and give it the same name as the project builder and then try to validate the archive project from the Xcode. if the validation is success then you can submit it to the app store and if not let me know what error you get while you validate the app so that we can look more in deep.

thank you.